# Python login page with keyauth

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a little problem in my code.
I am developing an application login using a key, but I am not well versed in python.
I want the user to enter the key into the "entry" window, and the login button checks it and allows/denies access to the entrance.
I use keyauth.cc in your project.

My code ->

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
from tkinter import messagebox
from keyauth import api
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time
import platform
import os
import hashlib
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Users\Razy\Desktop\KeyAuth-Python-Example-main\build\assets\frame0")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


window = Tk()

window.geometry("700x350")
window.configure(bg = "#121212")

def minimize_window():
    window.iconify()

def close_app():
    window.destroy()

canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#121212",
    height = 350,
    width = 700,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
    350.0,
    179.0,
    image=entry_image_1
)
entry_1 = Entry(
    bd=0,
    bg="#9F9F9F",
    fg="#000716",
    highlightthickness=0
)
entry_1.place(
    x=260.0,
    y=165.0,
    width=180.0,
    height=26.0
)

canvas.create_rectangle(
    271.0,
    200.0,
    428.0,
    201.0,
    fill="#3E3E3E",
    outline="")

canvas.create_text(
    291.0,
    139.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Enter your key here",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("SedgwickAveDisplay Regular", 14 * -1)
)

exit_button = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("exit.png"))
ext = Button(
    image=exit_button,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=close_app,
    relief="flat"
)
ext.place(
    x=676.0,
    y=12.0,
    width=10.0,
    height=10.0
)

min_button = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("min.png"))
min = Button(
    image=min_button,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=minimize_window,
    relief="flat"
)
min.place(
    x=658.0,
    y=12.0,
    width=10.0,
    height=10.0
)

canvas.create_text(
    19.0,
    12.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="GTA 5 RP BOTS",
    fill="#9F9F9F",
    font=("SedgwickAveDisplay Regular", 10 * -1)
)

def getchecksum():
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    file = open(''.join(sys.argv), "rb")
    md5_hash.update(file.read())
    digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    return digest

keyauthapp = api(
    name = "",
    ownerid = "",
    secret = "",
    version = "1.0",
    hash_to_check = getchecksum()
)


def check_license():
    key = entry_1.get()
    if keyauthapp.license(key):
        messagebox.showinfo("Успешная активация ключа", "Ключ активирован успешно.")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка активации ключа", "Введен неверный ключ.")

log_button = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("login.png"))
login_b = Button(
    image=log_button,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=check_license,
    relief="flat"
)
login_b.place(
    x=250.0,
    y=209.0,
    width=80.0,
    height=24.0
)


buy_btn = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("buy.png"))
buy = Button(
    image=buy_btn,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
)
buy.place(
    x=370.0,
    y=209.0,
    width=80.0,
    height=24.0
)
window.resizable(False, False)



subs = keyauthapp.user_data.subscriptions  # Get all Subscription names, expiry, and timeleft
for i in range(len(subs)):
    sub = subs[i]["subscription"]  # Subscription from every Sub
    expiry = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(subs[i]["expiry"])).strftime(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Expiry date from every Sub
    print(f"Подписка Истекает: {expiry}. Приятного использования!")

window.mainloop()
```

I made a function that takes the code from entry, and uses it to check through the login button, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Is there any error being thrown? And create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I guess you have used [keyauth.py from github](https://github.com/KeyAuth/KeyAuth-Python-Example/blob/main/keyauth.py).  If you look into the code, `api.license()` will call `os._exit(1)` if you pass invalid key.  Even you pass a valid key, `api.license()` return `None`, so the `if` statement inside `check_license()` will always be evaluated as `False`.  I would suggest to use `keyauth` module via `pip` instead.